# Как работать с сайтами, которые генерируют куки, либо токены в js

Tags: javascript, c#, http

Как я понял, мне в любом случае придется копаться в js сайта, и от туда изучать логику генерации куки/токена.
Есть ли какие-нибудь программы/расширения, которые позволяют отследить где генерируется куки/токен в js

Comment: Инструменты разработчика в браузере вам в помощь. В самих инструментах есть вкладка Cеть. Открываете, обновляете страницу, и идете читать, как работает [HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) ;)

Comment: http я знаю как работает, я ищу спообы, либо утилиты, которые помогают найти код js который генерирует куки

Comment: В инструментах разработчика слишком муторно искать как раотает js, хотелось бы найти что-то, что автоматизирует мой поиск в js

Comment: JS код не генерирует куки, их генерирует сервер и добавляет в ответ заголовки `Set-Cookie`. Браузер это видит и записывает эти куки в хранилище. Далее при каждом запросе браузер автоматически все подходящие куки из хранилища достает и добавляет в каждый запрос к серверу. JS тут вообще не при чем.

Comment: Тут скорей всего неверно задан вопрос, не куки, а нужные значения для отправки запроса (если конечно судить по этому [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1155753/220553)). Я не думаю, что такой инструментарий есть.

Comment: Ну а как тогда в запросе ни с того, ни с сего появляются кучу кук, которые до этого не устанавливались, и сервер их в ответе не возвращал

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, но теперь у меня на сайте другом появляются куки, погуглил названия этих куки, вот что нашел `urchin.js – использование файлов cookie
Раньше в Google Аналитике была доступна библиотека JavaScript под названием urchin.js. Когда появилась библиотека ga.js, разработчикам было предложено перейти на нее. Если сайт не был переведен на новую библиотеку, urchin.js создает файлы cookie так же, как ga.js. Дополнительную информацию можно получить в разделе ga.js – использование файлов cookie выше.`

Comment: Как я понял, они устанавливаются или генерируются js

Comment: Значит сервер их возращал ранее, например на этапе авторизации. Можете полностью вычистить куки, заранее открыть Сеть в инструментах разработчика и посмотреть, какие из ответов сервера содержат заголовки `Set-Cookie`. Там нет магии. JS конечно может работать с куками, но это скорее исключение в самых редких нестандартных ситуациях, так как в 99,9% случаев стандартное поведение браузера полностью закрывает вопрос с куками.

Comment: Как и в тот раз скажу вам, что без данных мы не можем вам помочь, а лишь дать какие либо догадки, не более. Инструментария нету, если как в том вопросе сайт генерирует некий id клиента, который сервер проверяет, то без разбора логики js я думаю вряд-ли получится что либо сделать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну сейчас посмотрел,у далил все куки, и непонятно откуда опять появляется куки https://retailedge.intel.com/50/landing?goto=%2f50%2femea%2fedgegames%2foverview, даже не нужно лоигнится, куки NID появляется сам, в ответе предыдущего запроса нету такого куки. После окончательной загрузки страницы, посмотрите куки, там тоже сами появляются подобные `__utma`

Comment: Ну начнем с того, что все указанные вами "печеньки" относятся к Google. NID [отлавливается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvViD.png) без проблем. А всякие `__utma` - это [аналитика гугла](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage?hl=ru) и тоже ставиться ими и они вряд ли нужны для работы сайта. Так что мне кажется, вы забиваете себе голову лишним.

Comment: Верно, там 80% кук - мусор от аналитики.